# setting up RPI TFT, GPIO and touchscreen questions

Tags: gpio, screen, touchscreen, pitft

I'm thinking of buying a Raspberry Pi TFT such as [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-8-TFT-LCD-expansion-display-touchscreen-for-Raspberry-Pi-B-B-Board-/171628940436?hash=item27f5e1cc94:g:R~MAAOSw6dNWTAOJ).

I would look into an official adafruit one, but I don't fancy paying £35 for a 2.8" screen...

a few questions though..

1. Is it compatible with a pi zero?
2. How do I access the available GPIO pins, and which ones are they?
3. Can I disable the touch-screen to have more free GPIO pins?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial, it tells you how to wire it...

I know that the adafruit screen works with the Pi Zero with a few bugs, but I am not sure what brand the eBay screen is, I suggest not to get it from eBay, there are lots of screens that are compatible for the Pi Zero.

This one works with the Pi Zero :

http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10001&productId=2213253&catalogId=10001&CID=GOOG&gclid=Cj0KEQiA4eqyBRDUh7Omv9vCtsoBEiQAspfs8ue4fo5YX9hWc2JmzuRg8PgoPzbu1qa3fhbU27-0vFoaAiIa8P8HAQ

Take a look in Amazon, it's a lot better and comes in cheaper...

Hope I helped, up votes for this answer is highly appreciated...

Comment: could you provide some links to the amazon screen and the tutorial?

Comment: Sure, tutorial - https://www.modmypi.com/blog/raspberry-pi-7-touch-screen-assembly-guide ......

Comment: Oops, apologies, I may be wrong about the price because when I was going through Amazon, the tft screens that take nearly all the the gpio pins (like the eBay link) come cheap, but the ones that take less gpio pins are more costly

Comment: The one that takes up nearly all of the gpio pins - https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00OUQHJK4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_UhDSxbTMX2E9G ---- £16.88

Comment: The display that was used in the tutorial that I sent - https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B014WKCFR4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_UkDSxb6PAHQPJ --- £64.99